# List taxonomy terms in Bolt CMS

Tags: bolt-cms

How is it possible to list all the terms in a taxonomy in Bolt? Not the terms applied to a record but all existing terms (like a tagcloud or a category list sidemenu)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Taxonomylist extension for that
http://extensions.bolt.cm/view/691bcf6f-02f9-4584-a275-baa210bfbe50

Answer (score 3):

Directly in the template, it could be done like this:

```
{% for category in app.config.get('taxonomy/categories/options') %}
    {{ category }}
{% endfor %}
```